# Set breakpoint on symbol with lldb

Tags: debugging, lldb

I am trying to set a breakpoint on a function but lldb gives me an error "WARNING: Unable to resolve breakpoints to any actual locations.."

Following their example over at http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html , I have to use breakpoint set --method xxxxxxxxx

The function where I try to set a breakpoint is called

```
 pf::WebViewImpl::~WebViewImpl()
 __ZN2pf11WebViewImplD1Ev
```

Which one should I use to be able to set a breakpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a breakpoint on your destructor using the `--method` option,

```
(lldb) br s -M ~WebViewImpl
```

You can use the `--name` option with just the dtor method name too,

```
(lldb) br s -n ~WebViewImpl
```

and lldb should find it.  Finally, you can pass the mangled name to `breakpoint set` and that will work as well,

```
(lldb) br s -n _ZN2pf11WebViewImplD1Ev
```

Note that there's only one underscore in the mangled name - `nm`(1)'s output will list a leading underscore that you need to omit.

If this method is in a shared library or framework and the process hasn't launched yet, then lldb is correct in saying "Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations".  Once your process starts running, the framework/solib will be loaded, lldb will evaluate all breakpoints and see that it now has a valid location.